# How to get only latest message when re-connecting to an existing consumer group in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

In my case, it is a valid possibility that a consumer is offline for a longer period. During that offline period, events are still published to the topic.

When the consumer comes back online, it will re-use its existing consumer group, which has been lagging. Is it possible to skip forward to the latest message only? That is, ignore all earlier messages. In other words, I want to alter the offset to the latest message prior to consuming.

There is the `spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset` property, but as far as I understand, this is only applicable for new consumer groups. Here, I am re-using an existing consumer group when the consumer comes back online. That said, if there is a possibility to automatically prune a consumer group when its consumer goes offline, this property could work, but I am not sure if such functionality exists?

I am working with the Spring Boot Kafka integration.

Comment: Can you use TTL to invalidate older messages?

Comment: Ideally, no, as I want the latest message to be available at all times.

Comment: Would compaction work to only keep the last value for each key?

Comment: @fafl It doesn't seem the question is asking about keys, only latest offset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use consumer seek method after you calculate the last offset then subtract one from that, commit, and start polling.

Otherwise, simply don't use the same group. Generate a unique one and/or disable auto commits, then you're guaranteed to always use the auto.offset.reset config and lag is meaningless across app restarts

Comment: When using a new group, how do you prevent your Kafka deployment from being polluted by obsolete groups? Is there a way to remove them automatically?

Comment: Also, I am wondering, if you substract one offset from the latest offset, is it guaranteed that this will point to the most recent message? That is, there are never gaps in offsets?

Comment: If you disable auto commits and don't commit manually, the offsets topic is never used. Otherwise, yes Kafka automatically removes unused groups (offsets.retention.ms). There are only gaps in compacted topics, and that's only guaranteed to be the most recent message after you queried for offsets, not after you start polling (there could have been more data produced if you're sending thousands of records per second, for example)

Comment: You can perform a relative seek with Spring for Apache Kafka https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#seek - using `-1` will seek to the last record (if `toCurrent` is `false`).